# Representation theory , $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: representation-theory, real-numbers

I am wondering if somebody could help me with this task. I have some problems with the theory of representations.

Let $\rho \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, $\rho(a) =  
 \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & a \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$.

1) Check that this is a representation of the group $\mathbb{R}$.

2) Is it irreducible?

3) Is it indecomposable ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: The first point I did. But how to check 2 and 3 I don't understand.

Comment: Do you mean a representation of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did the first point, I shall say nothing about that. It is not irreducible, because $V=\left\{(x,0)\,\middle|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is a stable subspace which is neither $\{(0,0)\}$ nor $\mathbb{R}^2$. But it is indecomposable, since there is no stable subspace $W$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2=V\oplus W$.